# upload new file first check if this file exist already in database or not then if not exist save that in database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to create sql database that contains

```
Image Id (int)
Imagename (varchar(50))
Image (image)
```

and in aspx write in upload button this code:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Condition to check if the file uploaded or not
    if (fileuploadImage.HasFile)
    {
        //getting length of uploaded file
        int length = fileuploadImage.PostedFile.ContentLength;

        //create a byte array to store the binary image data
        byte[] imgbyte = new byte[length];

        //store the currently selected file in memeory
        HttpPostedFile img = fileuploadImage.PostedFile;

        //set the binary data
        img.InputStream.Read(imgbyte, 0, length);

        string imagename = txtImageName.Text;

        //use the web.config to store the connection string
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Image (ImageName,Image) VALUES (@imagename,@imagedata)", connection);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = imagename;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagedata", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imgbyte;

       int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       connection.Close();

       if (count == 1)
       {
           BindGridData();
           txtImageName.Text = string.Empty;
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "javascript:alert('" + imagename + " image inserted successfully')", true);
       }
    }
}
```

When I'm uploading a new image I need to first check if this image already exists in database and if it doesn't exist save that in database.

Please how I can do that?

Comment: This question did not make it clear that you didn't want to update the image if it existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string cmd ="if not exists (select * from Image where ImageName= @imagename); ";
 \\if you want to check image data
 \\ (select * from Image where SUBSTRING(ImageName, 1, 8000)= SUBSTRING(@imagename, 1, 8000) ); 
 string cmd += "INSERT INTO Image (ImageName,Image) VALUES (@imagename,@imagedata)"; 
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);
```

If you want to verify imagedata, You can try to use `DATALENGTH` as first line of check for the two images.
If the `DATALENGTH` is different, then you suppose to have a "different" picture".
You can also use `SUBSTRING(Image, 1, 8000)` to check first 8000 bytes.
And also `SUBSTRING(Image, DATALENGTH(Image) - 7999, 8000)` to check last 8000 bytes.

Comment: This works too but it is faster to update and check row count that use an if exists. It only requires one table scan instead of two.

Comment: Thank you to  your answer
But is it possible that the condition by the image itself not by the imagename ?

Comment: Yes it is possible doing on the image itself.

Comment: but the image is store as image is that compare that true ?

Comment: You can try to use DATALENGTH as first line of check for the two images.
If the DATALENGTH is different, then you have a "different" picture".
You can also use SUBSTRING(photocolumn, 1, 8000) to check first 8000 bytes.
And also SUBSTRING(photocolumn, DATALENGTH(photocolumn) - 7999, 8000) to check last 8000 bytes.

Comment: thanks alot but can you tell me how i can do that in  simple code ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a method that is responsible for checking if the filename already exists in the table.

```
    private bool FileExists(string imageName)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()) // establish connection
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd =
                new SqlCommand("select 1 where exists(select Id from Image where ImageName = @)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@imagename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = imageName;
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I would call this like so

```
        if (fileuploadImage.HasFile && !FileExists(txtImageName.Text))
        {
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastest ways is to do an UPDATE and then INSERT if update returns no updates.

```
string cmd = @"UPDATE Image SET Image = @imagedata WHERE ImageName = @ImageName
               IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
                  INSERT INTO Image (ImageName,Image) VALUES (@imagename,@imagedata)";
```

Or if query on Image itself:

```
string cmd = @"UPDATE Image SET ImageName = @ImageName WHERE Image = @imagedata
               IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
                  INSERT INTO Image (ImageName,Image) VALUES (@imagename,@imagedata)";
```

Comment: `UPDATE` followed by `INSERT` is subject to races. `INSERT` with a `NOT EXISTS` followed by `UPDATE` on `@@ROWCOUNT=0` avoids this race

Comment: Your solution is a good solution. The question was to do no activity if the image already exists.

Comment: Emmanuele, the question was "image already exists in database and if it doesn't exist save". Thus checking it's not there before inserting.

Comment: thanks Lewis Harvey but his is query done correct if image already exist in sql i'm not want to update that just i want to not insert in sql another time  and show t the user the image is already exist

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this in `SSIS`:

- First check Filechapter table whether the same file name exists or not.
  If yes then delete the corresponding records from employee & file configuration table.
- After that insert new log into filechapter table with status as 'InProgress'
  and then load the data from new file into table.
- Load only valid records into destination table.
  Move all error records into a CSV.
- Implement the SCD type 1 (Insert/ Update)
- Once the execution is completed then update the filestatus like below.
  A. If execution is successful then populate the value as 'Success'
  B. If execution Fails then populate the value as 'Failed'.